# How to speed my linq query joing to table with a lot of data

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have an application using GPS readings. The table that holds the GPS reading which are sent after 10 seconds is growing big and big with over 2 millions records now. I also have another table with not more than 200 records. I am joining the two tables to get the most recent GPS readings and it takes a while, and since my web application sends request after every 30 seconds, it is actually discouraging with the speed of the query.
Anyone who knows how i can speed up my query?

Comment: Have you considered creating indexes for the columns that take part in the join? What data type are those columns? If they are varchar or nvarchar, you can change them to be ints.

Comment: post the code, it's easier to get accurate answers that way.

Answer (score 2):

LinqToSQL translates to SQL anyway so what you really need to optimize is the db query performance.

- Check your query in query analyzer and see what you can optimize.
- Add indexes.
- If possible post the query for review somewhere.

Comment: +1, can't really give a better answer with the lack of information provided.

Answer (score 0):

In a typical GPS application this is some kind of issue that every one will face :) Some of the options for you.

- Typically, a query in gps vehicle report will be based on your device id and date time. So try creating an index for these fields
- If you are having a table with geo-spatial data, create spatial indexes
- Try using table partitioning for the vehicle position data.
- Also try a little denormalization on the biggest tables to help reduce the load on queries

But all this will help only till some point till your load from increasing devices saturates your server performance. You need to workout how to shard your db as well.

Answer (score 0):

As Hasan Khan says; optimise your DB schema.

In addition, if it's only the most recent readings you need, how about creating another table that only holds the last *n* hours/days of data? This table would shadow the other in that you would insert the same data with the same PK removing 'stale' rows each time you insert.  One way of doing this is to maintain said table from an OnInsert trigger on the table that holds all data, or if you are using an SP to insert into the 'all data' table do it there.

The principal is this; take a small hit on insert performance to gain a big boost on select.